# TypeError: .select is not a function

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Recently, I have updated Mongoose from 5.7 to 6.4 and since then I have facing this issue.

```
 query = await db.DATABASENAME.find(JSON.parse(queryStr));
```

Earlier query.select("-meeting -__v"); query.lean() and some other were working fine. But, after update, I am getting:

**"TypeError: query.select is not a function"** and same for others.

Comment: maybe try logging the `db.DBNAME` just to ensure you have a vslif object

Comment: @matttm I have checked it, its logging the object; When i degrade my mongoose to 5.7 version, the same code works find

Comment: I have got the mistake, all thanks to stackoverflow :P

Answer (score 0):

The error was due to `await`, it is not returning the query but the object, `.select` can only be operated on query not the object, so the solution is to remove `await`.